# Storing ejabberd presence info in database

Tags: redis, erlang, ejabberd

Assuming this conceptual setup:

- ejabberd cluster (either instances in cloud or hosted SaaS)
- ejabberd MySQL database (some hosted solution elsewhere)
- website instances
- website MySQL database (same place as ejabberd database, but different database)

Also relevant is that currently the website instances already directly access the ejabberd MySQL database, in order to add new users (no need for rosters and other stuff like that, so xml_rpc overhead is avoided- though that might change in the future).

Now I want to write a module which will store presence info in a database that can be accessed from the website.

Which solution would be better for scalability and stability?

1. Add a new table to the ejabberd MySQL table and use the same sort of code that's used elsewhere in ejabberd for talking to the database to write presence info
2. Spin off http requests and let the webserver do the writing

I'm not familiar with Erlang and where the hangups/bottlenecks might be... I guess the two approaches are somewhat similar, and the database approach will be better since there's already internal support for connection pooling... but just wanted to check before starting to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other approaches that you can use, alternatively:

1. Query ejabberd to get the presence from memory. You can use HTTP for that, using XML-RPC or Rest API.

or

2. Use Redis Session backend for ejabberd and read sessions state from Redis. You may want to look into the [sm_db_type](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#session-management) option. It will only store a record, if the session is online, but not the actual presence of the user, for performance reason. This Redis approach does not change authentication back-end and is used for transient sessions.

Case 1 is more efficient, but may not be practical depending on how you plan to use presence. Case 2 is a bit less efficient, but in all cases, more efficient than using MySQL or HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks! Three quick followup questions- 1) Redis is only for transient data, will not serve login/pw right? 2) Presence is not automatically stored if using "sm_db_type: redis", rather I still need to write a simple module to store that? 3) What is the most efficient way to query ejabberd presence from memory, remotely (can be either via xmpp client or http or some other way- probably coming from google appengine)

Comment: btw- just to say, I am really loving the documentation and ease of use with ejabberd, and your help here on stackoverflow, much appreciated! (also- I tried writing a chat cluster thing in node.js + redis, and got frustrated with trying to solve cases of failed servers and things like that... excited to be using a battle-proven solution, even if just for r&d right now!)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. Regarding your questions: 1. Yes redis is for transient data. 2. What is stored in redis in the session state. You can know if user is online or not (but not the actual presence state that may change too often, for performance reasons) 3. To query ejabberd presence, you can use ejabberd XML-RPC or Rest API. Updated the answer to address your questions.

Comment: Cool. Just a bit confused- Option 1 (XML-RPC or REST API) is *more* efficient than querying Redis directly? All I need to know is whether or not a user is online btw, not the actual type of presence :)

Comment: It is not more efficient, it is an alternative: Store in Redis and query Redis directly or keep the session in ejabberd memory and query ejabberd.

Comment: gotcha- thanks! Where can I find info about how ejabberd stores online/offline status in redis? i.e. key name etc. I don't see that at http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#redis

Comment: We do not have doc on that yet, but created a ticket as a reminder to do it on ejabberd Documentation Github: https://github.com/processone/docs.ejabberd.im/issues/4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83809/discussion-between-davidkomer-and-mickael-remond).